# Truncamento não solicitado de Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Tenho um model destinado a gravar uma hora utilizada em uma tarefa:

```
public TarefaHoraPendente()
    {
        HorasAcumuladas = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
        Pausada = false;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo é obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Qtde. Máx.: 10 caracteres")]
    public string Identificador { get; set; }        

    [Required, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime HoraInicial { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime HoraReinicio { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan HorasAcumuladas { get; set; }

    public bool Pausada { get; set; }        
}
```

Quando crio uma nova entidade desse model alguns valores já vem preenchidos pelo Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        DateTime hoje = new ObtendoDataeHoraLocal();
        TarefaHoraPendente tarefaHora = new TarefaHoraPendente();
        tarefaHora.Data = hoje;
        tarefaHora.HoraInicial = hoje;
        tarefaHora.HoraReinicio = hoje;            

        return View(tarefaHora);
    }
```

Então todos tem a mesma informação, por exemplo: {07/04/2017 10:20:43} com Data, hora, minuto e SEGUNDOS.

Vai para View :

```
@model Models.Auxiliares.TarefaHoraPendente

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Projeto";
}

<h2>Iniciar marcação de horas</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Data)

        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Data)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Model.Data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            </dd>
        </dl>                

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Identificador, "Identif.(Máx.10 caract.)", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Identificador, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Identificador, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HoraInicial, "Hora inicial", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HoraInicial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HoraInicial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Iniciar contagem" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

E na View, o Campo HoraInicial já não mostra mais os segundos e não vejo nada que indique essa truncagem.

Alguém sabe dizer o que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: Acredito que seja a linha abaixo: @Model.Data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: Eu estava falando do formato do campo HoraInicial. Esse código é do campo Data. Apresentado com formato padrão. Não tem a ver com o problema que apresentei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em sua `View` você está passando um `DateTime` completo e o `EditorFor()` está com o campo do tipo `Time`. É a mesma coisa de você fazer isso:

```html
<input type="time" value="04/07/2017 01:59:00" />
```

Isso não irá funcionar mesmo, pois está passando uma data completa para um campo  que aceita somente o "tempo".

Para resolver isso, você pode utilizar o `DisplayFormat`, igual você utilizou na propriedade `Data` de seu Model. Porém, coloque o formato como `Time`, desta forma:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Required, DataType(DataType.Time)]
public DateTime HoraInicial { get; set; }
```

Assim você está especificando especificando que quer somente a hora da data.

Outro ponto é que o input do tipo `time` mostra/edita somente a hora e os minutos por padrão. Para mostrar os segundos, adicione o atributo [step](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML5_form_additions#step), conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<p>Sem step</p>
<input type="time" value="01:59:32" />

<p>Com step</p>
<input type="time" value="01:59:32" step="1" />
```

Veja o exemplo funcional [no DotNetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eUDLbp)

Comment: Aqui exibiu segundos nas duas formas.

Comment: @diegofm Num é possível editar, no outro não

Comment: Valeu, era isso mesmo. Bastou colocar o Format. Obrigado.